# JQ insert Array into an object

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I am working with a large dataset, I am using JQ to construct an object containing only the data I am interested in. To help with the question I have provided sample data to help illustrate my problem.

So far, I have only found a way to add 2 objects or 2 arrays, but I want to take a set of flat fields, and add an array as a subObject to the main json.

tmpData.txt

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batter": [{
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular",
        "status":{
            "complete": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate",
        "status":{
            "complete": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry",
        "status":{
            "complete": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "type": "Devil's Food",
        "status":{
            "complete": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

So far, the closest I have come is this

`cat tmpData.txt | jq '[{id, type}] + [(.batter[] | {batterId: .id, complete: .status.complete})]'`

which outputs the top level fields only 1 time, but each batter is it's own object, I need this whole output to be 1 object.

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut"
  },
  {
    "batterId": "1001",
    "complete": false
  },
  {
    "batterId": "1002",
    "complete": false
  },
  {
    "batterId": "1003",
    "complete": false
  },
  {
    "batterId": "1004",
    "complete": false
  }
]
```

**My ideal output would look like the following:**

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"batter": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "complete": false
    },
    {
    "id": "1002",
    "complete": false
    },
    {
    "id": "1003",
    "complete": false
    },
    {
    "id": "1004",
    "complete": false
    }]
}
```

As you can see there is 1 single object that contains everything I need to know, and there is no duplicate or extraneous data. I want to output a single object that contains an array of batters with ID and their status.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it shorter, clearer, more consistent, and complete. For example, the "ideal output" is truncated.  Also, the .batter array of the "ideal output" has elements of the form {id:_, complete:_}, but your attempts have "batterId" and "status".

Comment: @peak thanks. I have updated the question to be clear and corrected the filters. I believe you answered my last question, this is an extension off of that.

Comment: Shortened question for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq only supports adding the same data type using the `+` operator. You cannot add an array to object, or vice versa.

In order to add an array to an object, we must wrap the array in an object, and provide the key for the object containing the array. This makes sense if we think about json structure and how an array would be represented in a json object

The following command will work against the `tmpData.txt` file

`cat tmpData.txt | jq '{id, type} + {Batters: [(.batter[] | {batterId: .id, batterType: .type, status: .status.complete})]}'`

Outputs

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "Batters": [
    {
      "batterId": "1001",
      "batterType": "Regular",
      "status": false
    },
    {
      "batterId": "1002",
      "batterType": "Chocolate",
      "status": false
    },
    {
      "batterId": "1003",
      "batterType": "Blueberry",
      "status": false
    },
    {
      "batterId": "1004",
      "batterType": "Devil's Food",
      "status": false
    }
  ]
}
```